# How to make application to initialize before first request?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I have an application which i run from Intellij IDEA. In global object i have an onStart hook, which starts Akka jobs.

When i run this application it didn't initialize until i trigger request to one of controllers.

Is it possible to make framework initialize eagerly?

Comment: Yes.. run it in production mode, and not dev mode. i.e. `activator start`. Dev mode starts the server on the first request in order to account for reloading the application when the source changes.

Comment: thanks @m-z for clarification. I should not worry about this behavior.

Comment: @m-z, maybe you should post this comment as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct and will work in the production mode as desired. After the application is started, the onStart() method from your [GlobalSettings](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.GlobalSettings) implementation. is called before any request is served.

To facilitate development in the dev mode, it works slightly different and the framework restarts the server automatically after changes are made to the source code but does it only after the first request is made. Why? If the framework ware to restart every time code was updated, it would constantly rebooting. Hence, the first request is used as a trigger to start the process.